# Is it possible to use Microsoft dev tunnels to connect to an emacs server running on Azure?

Tags: emacsclient, server

I'm in an environment where Tramp/ssh is not possible as a means of remote editing. However, developers using VSCode are able to connect their local versions of vscode to the remote vscode server using Microsoft Dev Tunnels https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/dev-tunnels/

This setup is really nice, and given that emacs is already setup to connect to a remote server I figured that it might be possible to replicate this VSCode functionality.

I have tried configuring my emacs server to run on port 3333 and then have my emacs client connect to the dev tunnel over TCP using a custom server file. The server file content is:

```
********-3333.use.devtunnels.ms:3333 6360
1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

(I've configured the `server-auth-key` to be all `1`s)

However it always reports:

```
emacsclient: connected to remote socket at 255.255.255.255
emacsclient: connect: Address family not supported by protocol family
emacsclient: error accessing server file "/Users/cowboyd/.emacs.d/server/remote"
```

Is there some way to connect to a remote windows vm using emacsclient over TCP using windows devtunnels?

Comment: Why is the address 255.255.255.255? That’s obviously wrong.

Comment: That's a great question. I've edited the answer to contain the content of the server info file

Answer (score 0):

From a quick skim of the documentation, it appears that you can run `devtunnel host -p 3333` on the server, Then, on your local computer, run `devtunnel connect TUNNELID`. Now connect Emacs to the server at `localhost:3333` by creating a server file containing the local end of the tunnel (which is `localhost:3333`). Don't put the address of Microsoft’s HTTP(S) proxy (which is on the devtunnels.ms domain) here, because Emacs doesn’t use HTTP(S) to talk to the server.

If this doesn't work, you’ll have to ask your question in a forum dedicated to these Microsoft tools.

Comment: Unfortunately, running `dev tunnel connect` fails saying that I have insufficient permissions. However, running with VSCode works without any elevated permissions. Also, if I create an http server on the remote end per the instructions, I am able to see and interact with it without any extra steps other than running `devtunnel host` on the remote VM.

Comment: Those sound like problems with the tool, not Emacs. You should ask questions about it in a more appropriate forum. However, just to be sure, did you log in before running the `connect` command?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with the tool or with Emacs, it's just a matter of figuring out how to get them to talk together. As for the choice of forum, I disagree. This is not an obstacle for other users of the tool (VSCode users, generic http web service users, etc..). It's an obstacle for Emacs users, and if  down the road one tries to get this working, I should think it would be very helpful for them to have an answer.